# Is it true that Grodno airport recently got a higher category? What is it, what does it mean?

Tags: airport, international

[Grodno Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grodno_Airport) (IATA: GNA, ICAO: UMMG) is an airport that serves Grodno, Belarus. It is close to the European Union border and Polish politicians says Belarus plans to use it to make the EU immigration crisis worse, because Belarus just changed its category:

> The airport in Grodno was given a higher category by the authorities. [...]
>
> The Belarusian authorities have decided that the airport in Grodno will have the status of an airport where international flights can take place [...]

([kresy24.pl](https://kresy24.pl/lotnisko-w-grodnie-dostalo-od-wladz-wyzsza-kategorie-bezposrednio-przy-naszej-granicy-mozemy-sie-spodziewac-lotow-z-migrantami-z-poludniowej-czy-z-polnocnej-afryki/), translated by Google)

Political issues are the reason for this question, but I'm not interested in that part here. **I want to know the raw facts** - did this change happen? And what does it mean in terms of passenger volume, flight distances etc.? What actually changed, if it changed at all?

Comment: Define "higher category."

Comment: @JuanJimenez wish if I knew. I can't just go ask members of my government what they meant by category, I'm just a regular guy. I guess everything that affects how far flight it can accept or how many people can go though monthly should count.

Comment: Do you have an article or something that quotes the exact language used?

Comment: For example: https://kresy24.pl/lotnisko-w-grodnie-dostalo-od-wladz-wyzsza-kategorie-bezposrednio-przy-naszej-granicy-mozemy-sie-spodziewac-lotow-z-migrantami-z-poludniowej-czy-z-polnocnej-afryki/

Comment: FWIW, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grodno_Airport) says "Since 1993, the airport is allowed to perform international flights." Not sure what *category* they are talking about.

Comment: EU-Belarus [border crossing](https://www.dw.com/en/eastern-eu-countries-urge-un-action-over-belarus-migrant-row/a-58956196) background. On the question itself, categories relating to [international airports](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Documents/edocs/fasid/AOP1.pdf) are used, e.g. [for Australia](https://www.infrastructure.gov.au/infrastructure-transport-vehicles/aviation/international-aviation/international-airports). It mostly deals with prior approval for the flight.

Comment: @Mołot The problem with your question is that the term "higher category" is meaningless in an IATA context, so any answers are likely to be opinions. You might want to write to the media outlet or the author or the piece to ask for an explanation of what that means.